# Uncaught Error : error 1114 in electron

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, electron, native

I'm making a simple hello world application on electron using native C++, but getting this `Uncaught Error : error 1114` error. This error is specifically when project runs on Windows whereas it works good on Fedora.

[image: Uncaught Error : error 1114 in electron]

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "nodec",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron-packager": "^8.7.0"
    }
}
```

`binding.gyp`:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "addon",
            "sources": [ "addon.cc" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`addon.cc`:

```
#include <node.h>
namespace demo {
using v8::Exception;
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Number;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;

void hello(const FunctionCallbackInfo& args) {
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"world"));
}

void Init(Local exports) {
NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", hello);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
}
```

`main.js`:

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/addon');
console.log('This should be eight:', addon.hello());
```

`index.html`:

```
<title>My C++ App</title> Hello <script> require('./main.js') </script>
```

I have configured and build the project several times but that doesn't seem to be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have several flaws in your code:

- `addon.cc`: `FunctionCallbackInfo` and `Local` must have template parameters. Corrected function signatures are:

```cpp
void hello(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
void Init(Local<Object> exports)
```

- `package.json`: Your entry point should be

```json
"main": "main.js",
```

Second, you have to build your addon specifically to `electron` as described in [guide](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#manually-building-for-electron). For example, building it to latest `electron` release (1.4.13) use the following command:

```
node-gyp configure build --target=1.4.13 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

*(`--arch` flag according to your platform)*

After all of these, it runs successfully with

```
npm run start
```

printing `This should be eight: world` to console

---

As you don't use your `index.html` anywhere in your code - although probably your goal is to print there - you can try these improved `main.js` and `index.html`:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  new BrowserWindow().loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My C++ App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>
        Hello 
        <script>document.write(require('./build/Release/addon').hello())</script>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result showing `Hello world` in browser window

[image]